# Proof of matrix inverse definition in component notation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, tensors

reading a book on continuum mechanics, I got stuk in a trivial fact about the definiton of matrix inverse: given a tensor **$A$**, its component $A_{ij}$ si defined by $A_{ij}=e_{i}\cdot Ae_{j} \;(1)$, where $\left\{ e_{i}\right\} _{i\in \mathbb{N} } $ is an orthonormal basis. The inverse of $A$,  $A^{-1}$, is defined in the traditional way  $$$$ $ \\  AA^{-1}=A^{-1}A=I \; \; (2)$.$$$$ If we express the definition below in components notation we shall have  $$$$ $ A_{ik}^{-1}A_{kj}=A_{ik}A_{kj}^{-1}=\delta _{ij} \; \; (3)$. $$$$ It seems reasonable that (3) could be obtained by applying the definition (1) and (2), that is $$$$ $   A_{ik}^{-1}A_{kj}= \left( e_{i} \cdot A^{-1}e_{k}\right) \left( e_{k}\cdot Ae_{j}\right) =
\left( e_{i}\cdot Ae_{k}\right) \left( e_{k}\cdot A^{-1}e_{j}\right) =\delta _{ij} \; (4) $  $$$$ but I get stuk and I ignore how to proof the second and the third equality of (4) using the definition (2); probabily I’m ignoring some fundamental property. Could anyone give  me some hints? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The first equality of (4) follows from (1) and (2). And so does the second equality. The fact that you write several equations into the same line seems to confuse you. Since you know (2) you don't have to worry how to transform $\left( e_{i} \cdot A^{-1}e_{k}\right) \left( e_{k}\cdot Ae_{j}\right)$ into $\left( e_{i}\cdot Ae_{k}\right) \left( e_{k}\cdot A^{-1}e_{j}\right)$.

Comment: Hi Kurt, thank you a lot for your  answer, my doubt is if the definition (3) **follow** directly  from (2) only  by applying the definition of tensor component (1), that is, given two tensors  $A$ and $B$ such that $AB=BA=I$  , we get $A_{ik}B_{kj}=_{(1)}\left( e_{i}\cdot Ae_{k}\right) \left( e_{k}\cdot Be_{j}\right) 
=\delta _{ij}$.

Comment: $A_{ik}B_{kj}= ( e_{i} \cdot Ae_{k}) ( e_{k}\cdot Be_{j})$ is ***without doubt*** another way of writing $AB$. I do honestly not understand your problems.

Comment: I know that it is probably a stupid or too philosophic question, and probably I don’t have express it clearly; what I mean is the follow: think tensors as an abstract entities for which we can state the following property: $B$ is the inverse of $A$ iff $AB =BA=I$. Now if we define the quantity $A_{ij}:=e_{i}\cdot Ae_{j}$, how can be proved that $A_{ik}B_{kj}=B_{ik}A_{kj}=\delta _{ij}$?

Comment: Because that's exactly how the abstract relation $AB=BA=I$ is written after you have chosen a basis $\{e_1,...,e_n\}$ so that you can manipulate tensors through their compontens $A_{ij}$ and $B_{ij}.$

Comment: Hi Kurt, thanks for your patience; what I was looking for was the following algebraic steps: $A_{ik}B_{kj}=\left( AB\right) _{ij}=e_{i}\cdot \left( AB\right) e_{j}
=e_{i}\cdot Ie_{j}=e_{i}\cdot e_{j}=\delta _{ij}$.  I have been so blind! Thanks for your willingness